# What does the word "Slay-Cation" mean here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the meaning of the word "Slay-Cation" in the following sentence from the description of this drag queen show ([link](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/716-summer-slay-cation-tickets-304457008107?aff=ebdsoporgprofile)):

> *The 5th show of our Summer **Slay-Cation** is coming in hot with this cast of our fabulous queens!*

Comment: It's unclear to me. It's likely a play on "slay" + "stay-cation". "Slay", in this context, probably has the slang meaning of "be very funny" or "be very successful". "Stay-cation" means staying home during your holiday, rather than going away. I don't see what the connection would be to a live drag queen show, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @gotube "slay" is commonly used in drag in a similar way to "bravo", i.e. to congratulate an especially good performance. It is also used to wish that someone gives such a performance (where one otherwise might say "break a leg") and can also just be used as a verb meaning "to give a good drag performance" or "to look fabulous (especially in drag)". If you google "yass queen slay" or similar you'll be able to find lots of instances of its use relating to drag

Comment: Note that the literal meaning of the word "slay" is to "kill". If those familiar with drag queen culture (or who have researched it) say it has another meaning in that context, I accept that, could well be. I just bring this up to make the point that if you talked about a "slay-cation" without giving context, most English speakers would understand that you were making some joking comparison to a mass murder. (Well, unless you normally hang around with mass murderers. Then it might be literal.)

Comment: I think it's related to "kill" in the sense of "[to kill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kill#English)" (4: to amaze, exceed, stun or otherwise incapacitate) and "[to kill it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kill_it#English)". AFAIK, this sense of "slay" originates in [the ballroom scene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_culture) but I think this meaning has spread so widely that people even casually interested in watching drag shows are expected to recognise this sense of the word.

Comment: It's just a play on words: slay-cation, summer. See? They will slay the other contestants with their great summer outfits, etc.

Comment: @Jay I don’t think that’s quite true anymore. The use of _slay_ as a positive intensifier is so widespread now – not just in drag circles, but in popular culture in general – that I think most English speakers, at least younger speakers, would recognise it and not assume any relation to murder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the word "slay-cation" is a portmanteau (a word made by blending at least two words), just like the word "staycation", a combination of "stay" and "vacation". So "slay-cation" should probably mean "a slay vacation", whereas the word "slay" means "to complete something amazingly or perfectly".

Comment: Note also that this is probably an "improvised" portmanteau (i.e., specifically created for this event), rather than a conventional one (already a word in common use before this event, like "staycation").

Comment: *Somebody* made up the word "staycation"... and I wish they hadn't.

Comment: @RBarryYoung _Slay_ seems particularly prone to such nonce portmanteaux (noncemanteaux?) – or perhaps rather, the people who use _slay_ a lot also tend to be the kind of people who make up portmanteaux on the fly. _Slaycation_ is one, and I also know of at least _sliving_ (slaying + living, courtesy of Paris Hilton) and _Q and slay_ (Q&A, courtesy of Tyler Oakley). I’m sure I’ve heard others too, though I can’t bring any to mind right now.

Answer (score 13):

Since it also uses the word "queens" like this, then "slay" is likely to have the same meaning as this group of people use it for:

> something you tell someone when they look sexy as f***

> this word means to to something and do it well.

> It's like when u lookin hella good and you can pull anything off to make it look good

> succeeded in something amazing.

[All from Urban Dictionary.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slay)

So a "slay-cation" is a portmanteau that combines this meaning of slay with the word "vacation." In your case it's probably the name of a holiday event that celebrates or parades sassy, hot, flirtatious, powerful, successful, confident (any of these attributes) women or drag queens.

Answer (score 1):

"Slay-Cation" seems to be a proper noun here referring to a specific drag show and is not a phrase that is likely to be used outside that context.  https://absolutely-dragulous.com/show-dates

As the other answers said, this is a play on the slang word staycation and the word staycation is a portmanteau of the words stay and vacation used to describe a vacation where a person stays home to avoid the stress of travel.

Comment: Hi Luke, welcome to ELL! I don't see what your answer adds to the existing ones. That it is referring to a specific show doesn't change the meaning, which is what the OP is after.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate for me to remove the second half of my post?  I figured the information that this is a name for a specific event and not a word that would be used outside of that context would be useful.